# changing language on microsoft visual c++ 2010 express

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am new to the forum. I want to know how to change the language from Spanish to English in Microsoft Visual Studio c++ 2010 express edition.
I have tried to change it under tools>options>international settings, but still no change is seen.

Comment: The cleanest solution is to reinstall. Start directly with [VS 2013 Community Edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx), no need to use outdated stripped version.

Comment: Language settings shows only espanol. It is mandatory to use the 2010 version of VC++ in our institution.

Comment: (1) You skipped the most important step from the link above: `Install your version (German). Once the installation is finished you can install the English trial version: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional Trial - Web Installer...`. (2) If they all use 2010, at least consider a possibility of changing the institution ;)